# When a proposition is satisfiable and valid?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

The statement of the problem is confusing me. I don't understand whether it is asking for the definition of satisfiable proposition and valid proposition separately, or it is asking when a proposition is both (satisfiable and valid). Following is the approach of mine for later case.

> A statement is satisfiable if it contains a model having truth value
> $T$ and a statement is valid if the truth values of all of its
> models are $T$. So the the a statement is satisfiable and valid if it
> is a tautology.

What should I do? Whether I consider the definitions separately or tautology as the answer to the problem?

Comment: I don't see a problem being stated in the excerpt, just two assertions being made (the second of which is somewhat garbled in its "the the a").

Comment: what does "contains" mean?

Comment: Are you satisfied wit the answer below? If not, please ask more. If yes, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two definitions:

> [satisfiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability): there is a model (or: [interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(logic))) such that the statement is true in it.

Example: $p \lor q$ is a formula of propositional logic that is satisfied (evaluated to true) by a [valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(logic)) (or: truth assignment) $v$ such that $v(p)= \text T$.

> [valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity_(logic)#Valid_formula): a statement is valid when it is true in every model.

Example: $p \lor \lnot p$ is a formula of propositional logic that is valid by every valuation.

Obviously, every valid statement (formula) is satisfiable, but not vice versa. Thus

> a *valid* formula is *satisfiable* **and** *valid*.

A [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)) (in propositional logic) is a formula that is true in every valuation; thus it is a valid formula.